# Use the "first form" of Principle of Math Induction to prove the Well Ordering Principle.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction

Use the "first form" of Principle of Math Induction to prove the Well Ordering Principle. How can I do this? I tried doing it but I don't know where to start. Please I would I appreciate an explained answer rather than a hint. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well, I'm only going to give you a hint.  Let $S$ be a subset of natural numbers, and let $P(k)$ be the proposition that $k\in S$ implies that $S$ contains a smallest element.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is nonempty and has no minimum element. We know $1\not\in S$ since $1$ is a minimum element. Assume none of $1,2,..,k, k\in\mathbb{N}$ is an element of $S$. Since $S$ has no minimum element, $k+1\not\in S$. By induction, $S$ is empty. Thus, $\mathbb{N}$ is a well-order.